# How to have the text from a selected item inside a text field in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an edit function which displays in a dialog in my to do list app on flutter. When an item is selected to be edited, a dialog containing a TextField(to enter the new value of the selected item) and a button(to save the changes) appears. The goal is to have the text of the selected item on the TextField of the dialog, currently my code has a hintText inside the TextField that does display the value of the selected item but what I want to achieve is to have that in the controller.

If you didnt understood what I want to achieve see this edit function like instagram's one, when editing a post on instagram you don't have to type everything again instead when editing you have the original text of the post there. Well that is not happening on my app, when editing an item the TextField doesnt show anything. How can I make this work?

code related to the edit function

```
  List<ToDoElement> _toDoItems = [];
  TextEditingController _editController = TextEditingController();

  void _editToDoItem(String newText, int index) {
    setState(() {
      _toDoItems[index].task = newText;
    });
  }

  _editDialog(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
      return Dialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        insetAnimationDuration:
          const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          height: 180,
          width: 100,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
                Container(
                  height: 60, 
                  child: TextField(  // this is the textfield that I should have the text of the selected item inside.
                    controller: _editController,
                    autofocus: true,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    onSubmitted: (val) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                      _editToDoItem(val, index);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: '${_toDoItems[index].task}', //this hint text shows the value of the selected item, yhis is what I want to have but in the controller.
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      ),
                      
                    ),
                  )
                ),    
                Container(
                  height: 65,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5,),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text('EDIT', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _editToDoItem(_editController.text, index);
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ),                                          
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

full main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ToDoElement {
  String task;
  final DateTime timeOfCreation;

  ToDoElement(this.task, this.timeOfCreation);
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<ToDoElement> _toDoItems = [];
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _editController = TextEditingController();

  void _addToDoItem(String task) {
    if(task.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {  
        _toDoItems.add(ToDoElement(task, DateTime.now()));
      });
    }
  }

  void _editToDoItem(String newText, int index) {
    setState(() {
      _toDoItems[index].task = newText;
    });
  }

  void _removeTodoItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _toDoItems.removeAt(index));
  }

  _editDialog(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
      return Dialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
        ),
        insetAnimationDuration:
          const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          height: 180,
          width: 100,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
                Container(
                  height: 60, 
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _editController,
                    autofocus: true,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    onSubmitted: (val) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                      _editToDoItem(val, index);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17,),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: '${_toDoItems[index].task}',
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      ),
                      
                    ),
                  )
                ),    
                Container(
                  height: 65,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5,),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text('EDIT', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                    
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _editToDoItem(_editController.text, index);
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ),                                          
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _buildToDoItem(String toDoText, int index) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: Container(
        height: 58,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22.0, bottom: 12,),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1.5, color: Colors.red),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children:[
            Expanded(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  toDoText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                onTap: () => null,
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Edit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.5),),
              onPressed: () => _editDialog(context, index),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Delete', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.5),),
              onPressed: () => _removeTodoItem(index),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  int compareElement(ToDoElement a, ToDoElement b) =>
      a.timeOfCreation.isAfter(b.timeOfCreation) ? -1 : 1;

  Widget _buildToDoList() {
    _toDoItems.sort(compareElement);
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _toDoItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < _toDoItems.length) {
            return _buildToDoItem(_toDoItems[index].task, index);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            title: Text('To Do List', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),
          )
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          },
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 60,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 10,
                      child: Container(
                        height: double.infinity,
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _controller,
                          autofocus: true,
                          onSubmitted: (val) {
                            _addToDoItem(val);
                            _controller.clear();
                          },
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,),
                          
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Add a task here...',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                            ),
                            
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 4,    
                      child: Container(
                        height: double.infinity,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text('ADD', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                          
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _addToDoItem(_controller.text);
                            _controller.clear();
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                          },
                        ),
                      ),                                          
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ), 
              _buildToDoList()
            ]
          ), 
                 
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: As you can see in this image the dialog has popup and now as a hintText there is the value of the selected item, I need to have it in form of a controller so that there is actual text]

If you have any questions please let me know in the comments;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the `_editController` variable. You can use it not only to *get* the typed text but also to *set* it:

You can do it before calling the edit function, for example:

```
[...]
onPressed: () {    
                   _editController.text = toDoText;
                   _editDialog(context, index);
},
[...]
```

(Or maybe before creating the dialog, if you prefer.)

As you can see in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html):

> A TextEditingController can also be used to provide an initial value for a text field. If you build a text field with a controller that already has text, the text field will use that text as its initial value.

Comment: Hey, can you please explain to me how can adding `_editController.text = toDoText` solve the problem?

Comment: Is it because toDoText is the value that an item has and your are saying that it is equal to the texteditingcontroller right? If so why wasnt it required to use an index to identify the selected item? sorry I am trying to learn as much as I can